# No console output on Eclipse with Fortran

Tags: eclipse, fortran, fortran95

all. I'm writing a relatively simple program that iterates through a list of data and returns the peak values for a school project.

Here's the code so far:

```
    program Fortran_Project_1
    implicit none
    integer::cnt,cnt1, i
    integer:: peaks=5
    real, dimension(360):: time,impulse
    real, allocatable :: impulselist(:)
    integer, dimension(360)::interval
    character(len=150)::clean,header
    clean='C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fortran_Project_1\ir_clean.txt'
    print *, clean

    open (unit=1,file=clean)

    do cnt1=1,4
        read (1,*) header
    end do

    do cnt=1,443
        read(1,*) interval(cnt),time(cnt),impulse(cnt)
    end do
   print *, 'Choose amount of peaks to find'
   read *, peaks
   deallocate (impulselist)
   allocate (impulselist(peaks))
    do i = 1, cnt
        if (impulse(i)>impulse(i+1) .and. impulse(i)>impulse(i-1)) then
                peaks = peaks - 1
                impulselist(peaks) = impulse(i)
        end if
        if (peaks < 1) then
            exit
        end if
    end do
    close (1)
    print *, impulselist
end program Fortran_Project_1
```

Anyways, when running this and inputting the amount of peaks the user wants to find, the console is totally blank. It prints the clean variable and the query but that's all. What should I do?

Thank you

EDIT: Console output:

C:\Users\User\Desktop\Fortran_Project_1\ir_clean.txt
Choose amount of peaks to find

[Input]

Comment: A copy of the exact output would help as an illustration of your description.

Comment: Sure thing! Updated.

Comment: Compiling with bounds checking might reveal some problems as well (e.g. interval has a size of 360 and is filled till, non existing, element 443).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There was an issue with list dimensions. Here's the updated code that works perfectly.

program Fortran_Project_1
    implicit none
    integer::cnt,cnt1,i,count1,peaks
    real, dimension(1000):: time,impulse
    real, allocatable :: impulselist(:),timelist(:)
    integer, dimension(1000)::interval
    character(len=150)::clean,header
    clean='C:\Users\Buraaq Alrawi\Desktop\Fortran_Project_1\ir_clean.txt'
    print *, clean
    print *, 'Choose amount of peaks to find'
    read *, peaks
    allocate (impulselist(peaks))
    allocate(timelist(peaks))

```
open (unit=1,file=clean,action='read')

do cnt1=1,4
    read (1,*) header
end do

do cnt=1,501
    read(1,*) interval(cnt),time(cnt),impulse(cnt)
end do

count1=1
do i = 1, cnt
    if (impulse(i)>impulse(i+1) .and. impulse(i)>impulse(i-1)) then
            impulselist(count1) = impulse(i)
            timelist(count1) = time(i)
            count1 = count1 + 1
    end if
    if (count1 > peaks) then
        exit
    end if
end do
close (1)
100 format(A28,X,1000F10.2)
200 format(A28,X,1000F10.4)
300 format(A23,F10.2,F10.4)
write (*,100) 'The peak times are(seconds):', timelist
write (*,200) 'The peak impulse values are:', impulselist
write (*,300) 'The settled values are:',time(501),impulse(501)
```

end program Fortran_Project_1

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that you say that nothing happens. You should get an error message.

Array `impulselist` is not allocated and you are calling `deallocate(impulselist)`. That is not allowed and should be diagnosed by the compiler and it should complain when the code is running.

Comment: Oh okay. How do I go about fixing that? When getting rid of <code>deallocate(impulselist)</code> it tells me the array is already allocated.

Comment: Show us the **exact** error message and code. There is no way it could be allocated on that line in the code you show.

Comment: I have shown the exact error and code. That's all the information I have. I ran it on another computer and ran into the same issue.

Comment: Then I must stand by my answer. The code you show should print `Fortran runtime error: Attempt to DEALLOCATE unallocated 'impulselist'
` and exit. Please specify your compiler version and exact compilation flags.

Comment: I couldn't really find the compiler version. It's Eclipse for Parallel Application. At any rate, I figured out the issue